# Online Pathfinder

Tags: online, pathfinder-adventure

I'm looking for a website where a GM could create and design a Pathfinder game and host it on that site. The site must include:

1. Generators of NPC, encounter, dungeon, treasure, etc.
2. Players play "on that site"! That is to say, the player control the character by clicking the associated interface on that page. Whether it's movement or spell accessing.
3. Chat box or voice communications to show the interactions between the players.

Is there such a incredible website? Appreciated!!!

Comment: This appears to be about the RPG Pathfinder and not the Pathfinder Adventure Card Game.  As this question has escaped notice for so long, I'm closing rather than migrating.  If needed, please re-ask this question over on rpg.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There doesn't exist anything that fulfills all your requirements, but there are several good options that comes close.** One of the reasons are licensing, if anything outside the SRD are to be legally included. What you are looking for is called a [Virtual Tabletop (VTT)](http://rpgvirtualtabletop.wikidot.com/) environment, and here are four that comes close:

1. **[Roll20](https://roll20.net/)**

- Website
- Free, paid user get some advanced features
- Have (free) automated character sheet for Pathfinder (1E & 2E) available, among with tools to run a game, and chat environment where even complex rolls and other things can be outputted
- Pathfinder modules with maps, monster stats/tokens, handout available to purchase. (2E: Lots, 1E: limited)
- Paid accounts have access to more advanced feature like dynamic map lightning, and can use advanced community-created API Scripts
- Scripts exist for treasure generation, and the rest can be created with API Scripts

2. **[Astral](https://www.astraltabletop.com/)**

- Website
- Free, paid user get some advanced features
- Pathfinder (1E & 2E) character sheets and some modules supported
- no methods for advanced generators

3. **[Fantasy Grounds](https://www.fantasygrounds.com/home/home.php)**

- Program: Windows/Mac/Linux
- Game Master needs to buy, free for players
- Have character sheets for Pathfinder(1E & 2E) available, among with tools to run a game, and chat environment where even complex rolls and other things can be outputted
- Extensive catalogue of Pathfinder (1E & 2E) modules & sourcebooks  to purchase; with maps, monster stats/tokens, handouts
- Addons exists for various automation, treasure & encounter generation should be possible for PF with some tweaks

4. **[D20Pro](https://d20pro.com/)**

- Program: Windows/Mac/Linux
- 30-day trial, one-time purchase
- PF SRD and character sheet support for both 1E & 2E, limited modules & sourceboks

Beyond these options with official support from Pazio and content available, you can [look at other VTTs](http://rpgvirtualtabletop.wikidot.com/) that simply have the online rpg framework to play with, but might lack pathfinder-specific help. For some of the smaller VTTs you might need to created yourself, and the available community/documentation will be much smaller. There are VTTs with 3D environments available.

Comment: Welcome to Board and Cardgames Q&A. Nice first answer!